# Передать двумерный массив в функцию

Tags: c++, c

Есть программа:

```
int mas(int **mas) {


    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        int b = mas[i - 1][4];
        for (int j = 4; j > 0; j--) {
            mas[i][j] = mas[i - 1][j - 1];
        }
        mas[i][0] = b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int mas1[5][5] = { { 1,2,3,4,5 } };

    mas(mas1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            cout << mas1[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

ошибка: аргумент типа "int (*)[5]" несовместим с параметром типа "int **"

Что нужно сделать, чтобы передать этот массив в функцию?

Пробовал по разному через указатели передать, но так ни один из способов и не помог

Comment: В функцию надо передавать указатель на первый элемент, количество строк и столбцов. Как-то так -- `void print_arr2 (int *arr, int n_rows, int n_cols) { ... }`. Внутри функции вы обращаетесь к i,j-му элементу вот так `arr[i * n_cols + j]` (например, в функции печати -- `for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) { printf("row %4d ", i); for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++) printf("%10d ", arr[i * n_cols + j]); puts("");}`)

Comment: `int mas ( int ( * mas ) [ 5 ] ) {`